# How To Make Facebook Comments Preview Different Open Graph Tags from 1 URL

Tags: php, html, facebook-opengraph

I saw those Facebook Posts that ask "Which Marvel Superhero Are You?" or "Which Pokemon Are You?" and then tells you to type a URL into the comment of the post, and it would give you an answer in your comment preview pane like "You're Spiderman. Like it? Share this."

I tried to do something similar yesterday. And I chose Wonder Woman Movie as the theme.
I have coded a simple webpage as a simple "Which Wonder Woman Movie Character Are You?" Page. It will auto randomly choose one character for you. So basically, I have a php file. In it, I put a php array that assigns 3 different html files(Steve, Wonder Woman & Antiope). Then a randomizer code will auto select from 0,1,2, the numbers of the array slots. And fetch the html page by using readfile() as your character. The only additional thing I put was .htaccess to redirect test_wonderwoman.html to the php page. So everytime you access the test_wonderwoman.html page(which by the way does not exist), it will auto direct to test_wonderwoman.php and once you get there, when the browser is refreshed, it'll get a random character. Sometimes you might get the same character twice or thrice in a row, because it is random assigned and I only have 3 characters for now.

I can get this to work on the webpage itself. But I couldn't get it to work in Facebook. In Facebook, it's supposed to give a preview pane of the character and a description whenever someone posts the URL as a page post or as a comment under a post. That happens because of the Facebook Open Graph meta tags that are added in the   tags of the html. I was told that the Facebook webcrawler will access the page from my free webhosting server, so that is why I tried using PHP to tell my server to serve the FB crawler a random html page whenever it is requested.

It is not working in Facebook. It doesn't randomize. It keeps showing one character repeatedly. Also because my webpage is new and not many people have shared the link, FB Security keeps asking me to key in random code numbers or else it will discourage me from posting the link.

By using the FB OG Debug console, and using the scraper tool, it does tell me that their crawler is indeed seeing the different html pages randomly. It does see and fetch the wonderwoman.html page for example, but it still displays Steve Trevor page in the preview pane.

Note: I modifed the .htaccess page. Because I was thinking later I could have a nicer named URL that directs to the test_wonderwoman.php page. Right now it's redirecting https://oskuek.000webhostapp.com/test_wonderwoman.html to that.

I can't figure out what's wrong. Could you help me please? Thanks.

```
.htaccess 
# HTID:1508814: DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY THIS LINE AND THE LINES BELOW
php_value display_errors 1
# DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY THIS LINE AND THE LINES ABOVE HTID:1508814:

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^test_wonderwoman\.html?$ /test_wonderwoman.php [NC,R,L]



test_wonderwoman.php page
<?php 
$RandomList = array(); // Leave this line as is.
// Edit next lines for the file locations to be inserted randomly.
$RandomList[] = "/wonderwoman.html";
$RandomList[] = "/antiope.html";
$RandomList[] = "/stevetrevor.html";

// Leave next line as is.
readfile($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$RandomList[rand(0,2)]);

?>


stevetrevor.html page
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>You are Steve Trevor</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Like it? share with friends" />

    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="oskuek.000webhostapp.com" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="You are Steve Trevor" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="Like it? share with friends" />

    <meta property="og:image:width" content="400" />
    <meta property="og:image:height" content="400" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://oskuek.000webhostapp.com/images/stevetrevor400x400.jpg" />

</head>
<body>
<img src="images/stevetrevor400x400.jpg">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could show us what you tried..?

Comment: Hi, Ray. Yes, certainly. One moment please.

Comment: @Ray, I added the codes into my post. Please have a look. Thank you.